# signal pending list of new created thread is not empty?

Tags: linux, pthreads, signals

In the man page of [pthread_create](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create), it said:"**The set of pending signals for the new thread is empty**".
But I wrote some code for test, which got the opposite result that the signal pending list of new created thread is not empty. The code is bellow:

```
void* thread_fun(void* arg)
{
    int s;
    sigset_t pendingset;

    s = sigemptyset(&pendingset);
    if(s != 0)
    {
        printf("sigempty error.\n");
    }
    else{
        s = sigpending(&pendingset);
        if(s == 0){
            if(sigismember(&pendingset, SIGINT))
                printf("SIGINT in pending signal list.\n"); // this msg is printed
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid;
    sigset_t set;
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);

    sleep(10); // send SIGINT to the process using kill -SIGINT pid
    printf("before create thread...\n");
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_fun, NULL);

    pthread_join(tid, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

During the sleep period, I sent the SIGINT to the process. Because the sigmask set including SIGINT, at that point the received SIGINT signal was pending in the signal list. After the pthread_create, in the new thread, sigpending return the pending signals of the calling thread, and the SIGINT is included in the set. So it's inconsistent with the man page.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that signal you sent is a process-level signal, so it's pending for the whole process (and all threads that have it blocked), whether it was pending before the thread was created or not. The [docs for `sigpending()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/sigpending.html) says (emphasis added):

> The `sigpending()` function shall store, in the location referenced by the set argument, the set of signals that are blocked from delivery to the calling thread and that are pending **on the process** or the calling thread.

If the signal pending when `pthread_create()` is called was a thread-level signal, then it wouldn't be pending on the newly created thread.  You can test this by sending the signal using the `pthread_kill(pthread_self(), SIGINT)` function.

I do agree that the wording about pending signals being cleared for new threads isn't very clear about this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And I also find the explain from the sigpending() man page in die: The set of signals that is pending for a thread is the union of the set of signals that is pending for that thread and the set of signals that is pending for the process as a whole